# Swing Execution

Tags: java, swing

Hi I just wrote a code for a Swing using Menu bar. But the problem arises in running. I type:

```
javac Menu.java
java Menu
```

It gives no errors but the GUI does not get displayed. Here's my source code for reference:

```
import javax.swing.*;
class Menu extends JFrame
{
    JMenuBar mb;
    JMenu m1,m2,m3;
    JMenuItem mn1,mn2,mn3;
    JCheckBoxMenuItem chk1,chk2,chk3;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem rd1,rd2,rd3;
    JSeparator sp1,sp2,sp3;
    Menu()
    {
        setTitle("MenuBar Demo");
        mb = new JMenuBar();
                m1 = new JMenu("File");
                m2 = new JMenu("Edit");
                m3 = new JMenu("View");
                mn1 = new JMenuItem("New");
                mn2 = new JMenuItem("Open");
                mn3 = new JMenuItem("Close");
                chk1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Cut");
                chk2 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Copy");
                chk3 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Paste");
                rd1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Find");
                rd2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Find Next");
                rd3 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Replace");
                sp1 = new JSeparator();   
                sp2 = new JSeparator();   
                sp3 = new JSeparator();   
                m1.add(mn1);
                m1.add(mn2);
                m1.add(sp1);
                m1.add(mn3);
                m2.add(chk1);
                m2.add(chk2);
                m2.add(sp2);
                m2.add(chk3);
                m3.add(rd1);
                m3.add(rd2);
                m3.add(sp3);
                m3.add(rd3);
                mb.add(m1);
                mb.add(m1);
                mb.add(m2);
                mb.add(m3);
                getContentPane().add(mb);
                mb.setSize(300, 300);
                mb.setVisible(true);
    }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new Menu();
        }

}
```

Why does the GUI not appear?

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the constructor, call `this.setVisible(true);`

### General tips

- Don't extend frame, instead keep a reference to one.
- Don't call `setVisible(true)` on components, instead add them to a container that will be made visible.  The menu bar does not seem to be added to anything.  Add it using [`setJMenuBar(JMenuBar)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setJMenuBar%28javax.swing.JMenuBar%29)
- Don't set the size of components.  Use appropriate layouts, padding and borders then `pack()` the GUI.
- Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  It helps readability.
- & as Puce mentions, start and alter GUIs on the EDT.

These changes will produce a small GUI on-screen.

```
// ...
//getContentPane().add(mb);
setJMenuBar(mb);
//mb.setSize(300, 300);
//mb.setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
pack();
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I did add it. But there's no change

Comment: nice catch, that's what I was thinking as I read that question from the OP and here you are, as always, before me with better insight than I can possibly could share :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Menu app = new Menu();
            app.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

}

I suggest to rename your class, as this an application/ frame not a Menu.

Answer (score 3):

By Default JFrame visibility is `false`

you forgot to show frame `this.setVisible(true);`

So end of constructor add

```
mb.setSize(300, 300);
mb.setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(true);<<<Add here
```

**CODE:**

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Menu extends JFrame {
    JMenuBar mb;
    JMenu m1, m2, m3;
    JMenuItem mn1, mn2, mn3;
    JCheckBoxMenuItem chk1, chk2, chk3;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem rd1, rd2, rd3;
    JSeparator sp1, sp2, sp3;

    Menu() {
        setTitle("MenuBar Demo");
        mb = new JMenuBar();
        m1 = new JMenu("File");
        m2 = new JMenu("Edit");
        m3 = new JMenu("View");
        mn1 = new JMenuItem("New");
        mn2 = new JMenuItem("Open");
        mn3 = new JMenuItem("Close");
        chk1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Cut");
        chk2 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Copy");
        chk3 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Paste");
        rd1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Find");
        rd2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Find Next");
        rd3 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Replace");
        sp1 = new JSeparator();
        sp2 = new JSeparator();
        sp3 = new JSeparator();
        m1.add(mn1);
        m1.add(mn2);
        m1.add(sp1);
        m1.add(mn3);
        m2.add(chk1);
        m2.add(chk2);
        m2.add(sp2);
        m2.add(chk3);
        m3.add(rd1);
        m3.add(rd2);
        m3.add(sp3);
        m3.add(rd3);
        mb.add(m1);
        mb.add(m1);
        mb.add(m2);
        mb.add(m3);
        getContentPane().add(mb);
        mb.setSize(300, 300);
        mb.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Menu();
    }

}
```

Comment: @sribharath its works correct and i see JFrame on my machine.

Comment: Ok. Did you edit any part of the code apart from the setVisible property?